# Get kafka broker, consumer, producer metrics using confluent-kafka-go

Tags: go, apache-kafka, metrics, confluent-kafka-go

I cannot find any reference on implementation of getting metrics.
Can Someone help with an example and references?

Comment: Unclear what broker metrics you're looking for _from a client_, but look at [`stats_example`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/stats_example/stats_example.go#L93)

Comment: Yeah not sure what kind of metrics you are looking for but you can also check out [kafdrop](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop). It's a neat UI which displays information about brokers, topics, partitions, consumers, and also lets you view messages.

Answer (score 0):

As [stats_example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/stats_example/stats_example.go#L93) says here, You can get stats listed in [STATISTICS.md](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/STATISTICS.md). But clearly mentioned in the example comments, You need to implement metrics

> Stats events are emitted as JSON (as string). Either directly forward
> the JSON to your statistics collector,  or convert it to a map to
> extract fields of interest.

So in this case, In your application, you need to implement metrics collector something like [prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus)

And if you want full broker side metrics, You can implement Kafka monitoring As Kafka Documentation explained [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring)

> Kafka uses Yammer Metrics for metrics reporting in the server. The
> Java clients use Kafka Metrics, a built-in metrics registry that
> minimizes transitive dependencies pulled into client applications.
> Both expose metrics via JMX and can be configured to report stats
> using pluggable stats reporters to hook up to your monitoring system.